# Função JavaScript usando For

Tags: javascript, funções, if, for

Tenho um array com a altura de vários alunos e preciso classificar em grupos por altura. Eu faço um `for` para fazer a varredura do array e dentro do `for` uma condicional `if` para saber se o aluno entra nesse grupo, e então eu preencho o array de grupo.

O problema é que o array está preenchendo com espaços `null` e não sei se o erro é no `if`.

```
var alunos = [170, 159, 151, 187, 156,]

function qualGrupo(alunos) {

    for (var i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
        if (alunos[i] >= 150 && alunos[i] <= 159) {
            grupoA[i] = alunos[i]
        }
    }
}
```

O retorno está sendo assim: Seu array grupoA tem esses valores:

```
[,159,151,,156]
```

Não quero que fique com esses espaços em branco. Como faz?

Comment: De onde vem essa variável `grupoA`?  Você só precisa fazer o controle com alunos que estejam 150 e 159?

Comment: possivel duplicata https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/461226/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-javascript-criar-arrays-a-partir-de-outro-array

Comment: esse 154 no retorno caiu do céu?

Comment: Use `grupoA.push(alunos[i])` ao invés de `grupoA[i] = alunos[i]`

Comment: Leo Letto  grupoA foi a variável criada, e o controle seria isso mesmo.

Comment: Leo Caracciolo, tinham mais números no array aluno eu que esqueci  de colocar. sobre a duplicata não tinha encontrado antes. Obrigado

Comment: Rafael Tavares vou  tentar isso. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa pergunta é similar a essa [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/461226/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-javascript-criar-arrays-a-partir-de-outro-array) que foi fechada e resolvida pelos comentários

```js
  var alunos = [170, 159, 151, 187, 156,]; 
   
   var grupoA = [];
 
    for (var i=0; i<alunos.length; i++){
 
        if(alunos[i]>150 && alunos[i]<=159){
             grupoA.push(alunos[i]);
        }
 
    }
 
       console.log(grupoA.join());
       console.log(grupoA);
```

Mas se preferir outra forma

```js
var alunos = [170, 159, 151, 187, 156,]
var grupoA = [];
function qualGrupo(alunos) {

    for (var i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
        if (alunos[i] >= 150 && alunos[i] <= 159) {
            grupoA += alunos[i]+",";
        }
    }
    grupoA = grupoA.substring(0,(grupoA.length - 1));
}
qualGrupo(alunos);

console.log(grupoA);
```

Comment: Vou tentar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

ola, pelo que entendi, você deseja que o final fique [159,151,156,154].
Caso seja isso, troque o seu

```
grupoA[i] = alunos[i]
```

por

```
grupoA.push(alunos[i])
```

Deve resolver.